# A good way to know path to resources in a paths/installation/build independant way

Tags: c++, c, path, convention

In my GNU/Linux environment, my software would have all of its graphical resources installed under `/usr/share/pixmaps`. In Wintendo everything would go into `C:\Program files\myappname`. In a different OS, somewhere else.

What are the most common ways, conventions, good practices so I can abstract my way to refer to the files I open in my code in a paths/installation/build independant way? Basically a portable way to refer to resources paths.

Comment: The easyiest way is probably to have a config file, one per OS convention, which will describe the path to installed files.

Comment: OT: On Windows there are a variety of places where program data should be stored, depending on the context of the data (global configuration, per-user config, per user data files, public data files, etc.). Its a proper-thing, but it is also a UAC thing that should be adhered to or you'll likely face problems down the road. Look at the API docs on SHGetKnownFolderPath for more information on this. I only bring it up because you mention you desire to do this in a supported way in Windows, and C:\Program Files isn't a good choice, or even a valid choice, in most circumstances.

Comment: @WhozCraig I was talking about data files of the program itself, totally static data. I will take a look at SHGetKnownFolderPath, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a preprocessor `ifelse` chain of OS defines that `#defines` a function name mapped to a real function call that retrieves the correct path:

```
#if _WIN32
#define GetResourcesFolderString GetResourcesFolderStringW
#elif ((macintosh) || (Macintosh) || (__APPLE__ & __MACH__))
#define GetResourcesFolderString GetResourcesFolderStringM
#elif __gnu_linux__
#define GetResourcesFolderString GetResourcesFolderStringU
//...and so on
#endif

//...Later...

std::string GetResourcesFolderStringW() {
    return "C:/Program files/myappname/"
}
std::string GetResourcesFolderStringM() {
    return "Mac folder path here";
}
std::string GetResourcesFolderStringU() {
    return "/usr/share/pixmaps/";
}
```

This way you only call one function, and depending on your build target the correct function is called with no change in code.

Hard-coding the paths is generally not a good idea and is used here for illustration purposes only. You should probably set up a configuration file or similar to allow for individual systems to have separate install paths and still be able to find the resources.

Comment: [Pre-defined C/C++ Compiler Macros](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/) is always a good reference for looking up these things :-)